# In app purchase subscription vs consumable

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I'm making an app which will allow the user to purchase either a subscription or consumable which allows them to access data on a monthly basis. Once the new data for the next month is available they will download that and the previous data is invalid and actually illegal to use so it will be removed. So I'm not sure which to choose. A subscription model or a consumable model? From what I see either one would work. Any reason to choose one over another?

Comment: Quick question - is the developer responsible for determining whether an in-app purchase is consumable or a subscription? Or does Apple have the final say here?
Which did you end up going with, and did you encounter any interference from Apple about your decision?

Comment: The developer is responsible, although I assume Apple will review your choice. I ended up doing a consumable. I haven't finished the app yet so I don't know if they will object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with consumable in this case. Although it sounds like a monthly subscription model, it is not as the access to the previous item essentially runs-out or is consumed. The consumable model makes more sense.

Plus from a developers point of view, not having to make the content available across multiple devices (a requirement of the subscription model) can make things a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

a consumable item, if the user makes a restore the item will not be restored. Whereas subscription it can be if it is still valid.

Comment: Yes, and since with the subscription I have to make a server that keeps track of all that the consumable is easier for me. I'm kinda leaning towards a consumable, since that's more or less what it is in my mind.